# Specify plot title and facet title in Altair LayerChart

Tags: python, altair

Using the iris dataset we can create a simple faceted chart:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url

alt.Chart(iris, title='Main Title').mark_bar().encode(
    x='petalWidth:Q',
    y='count(petalLength):Q',
    color='species:N',
    facet=alt.Facet('species:N', title=None)
)
```

[image]

Here I can control both the main plot title and the title of the facets respectively.

Now let's say I want create the same chart, but add text annotations to each bar:

```py
base = alt.Chart(iris).encode(
    x='petalWidth:Q',
    y='count(petalLength):Q',
    color='species:N',
    text='count(petalLength):Q'
)

c = base.mark_bar()
t = base.mark_text(dy=-6)

alt.layer(c, t).facet('species:N', title=None).properties(title='Main Title')
```

[image]

This time, there is the `species` title above the facets. How can I control both the main plot title and the facet title in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keyword arguments passed to the `facet` method are passed through to the `alt.FacetChart` chart that is created.

Any keyword arguments you want passed to the facet encoding can be passed via an `alt.Facet()` wrapper, similar to other encodings.

For example:

```py
alt.layer(c, t).facet(
    facet=alt.Facet('species:N', title=None),
    title='Main Title'
)
```

[image]

Comment: would you mind updating your answer with the solution you mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1758)?

Answer (score 0):

```
gm_plot = alt.Chart(gm2018, width=200, height=150).mark_bar(opacity=0.7).encode(
alt.X('life_expectancy', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=30)),
alt.Y('count()'),
alt.Color('region')).facet( facet=alt.Facet(
'region:N', title="test where the title in the facet arg goes"),
        title={'text': ["can i pass a dict as in normal .properties()?",
                        " and get multilined titles"],
               "subtitle" : ["multilined subtitles too?", "yes"]})
```

[returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fkAQ.png)

Thanks for the question and the solution. The alt.Facet worked for my needs